# Display image from hyperlink source

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have an app that uses MVVM.

I have an image at the following hyperlink `http://b-i.forbesimg.com/spleverage/files/2013/04/silver-apple-logo-apple-picture.jpg` that I want to bind as source on my listbox.

See below in my listbox datatemplate I am binding the image source (which is a hyperlink) as follows. I would expect to see the image in the listbox, however nothing is loaded. What am i missing?

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="UserDataTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                <Image Source="{Binding Image}"></Image>
            </Grid>

            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

[image]

The value that is being passed in {Binding Image} is 'http://b-i.forbesimg.com/spleverage/files/2013/04/silver-apple-logo-apple-picture.jpg'. Any idea why the image wouldn't load?

Comment: Just tested here works fine, Is there any binding errors in your output window? perhaps give the image a width/hieght to make sure its not displaying the full size image and you are just seeing an empty orner of the image

Comment: Negative, tried with width, height, but still doesn't show anything. Any other ideas?

Comment: I added my test code below, it may help diagnose the problem

Comment: Snoop might help as well. http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/ You can examine elements and data contexts to make sure your bindings are correct, and investigate the properties of the Image element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I done a quick test and that Image is quite big, there is a chance it is there but because there is no constraint on the `Grid` size in your `DataTemplate` its just showing the full sized image and you can see it all, just an empty corner.

Using your `DataTemplete` I added a `MaxHeight` and it displayed ok.

TestCode:

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
        Items.Add(new Item{Name = "Stack", Image = "http://b-i.forbesimg.com/spleverage/files/2013/04/silver-apple-logo-apple-picture.jpg"});
        Items.Add(new Item { Name = "Overflow", Image = "http://b-i.forbesimg.com/spleverage/files/2013/04/silver-apple-logo-apple-picture.jpg" });
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Item> _items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set { _items = value; }
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Xaml:

```
 <Window x:Class="WpfApplication13.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="428" Width="738" Name="UI" >
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="UserDataTemplate">
                <Grid MaxHeight="25">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource UserDataTemplate}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much man. I think my problem is the type of hyperlink I have. The image is at the following hyperlink 'https://geeks.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/_api/_common/IdentityImage?id=cbfcb505-31c1-48af-a51a-63b9c2c398ab&__v=4' I suspect i may need to use something like an AbsoluteUri or something. Any idea how I can display an image off of this?

Comment: that link sends me to a visual studio login page, perhaps its inside your account or another accout that requires signing in, try moving the image to a publc location.

Comment: Make sense, I'll mark your answer for now. Thanks for the support.